# ActiveRecord pg adapter raw connection query returns strings for all data types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord, pg

I have a table that looks like

```
create_table "my_table", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name",        limit: 255
  t.integer  "size",       limit: 4
end
```

When I run

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM my_table")
result.to_a[0]["size"]
```

Will return "2", rather than 2.

I'm moving an app from MySQL to Postgres, and this wasn't an issue with the MySQL adapter, but pg seems to return strings for non-string types. Is there a way to have the datatypes of the result come from the db schema when using a raw query?

Comment: Your "name" field is a string. I assume the problem occurs for size?

Comment: Oops. You are correct. Will update.